# Showing credit/debit card types supported by careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, payment

I just tried paying for a careers subscription by Switch/Maestro debit card (a fairly popular payment method in the UK) but got a "card number invalid" error. I assumed that's because that card type isn't supported so used my MasterCard instead and it went through fine.

It might be worth showing the logos of the card types the payment page accepts just so it's clear.

I'm sure the people from the UK would also appreciate support for debit cards as they're in pretty wide use here, perhaps more so than credit cards.

Comment: I'm not even sure, if Americans know what debit cards are ;)

Comment: At least they're *called* "debit cards" in the US, which not at all true everywhere.

Comment: it gets more complex, most UK debit cards will work as credit cards outside of the UK, so will work on any site that takes credit cards.  One or two debit cards do not "fall back"...

Comment: Closing this as one site specific, as these topics belong on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have added logos for the various credit / debit cards we accept.  This will be pushed out in the next release.  Thanks for the feedback!